# Is there a way for me to see the soap request being sent? in C#?

Tags: c#, soap, soap-client

I'm a java developer and just today I've started learning C# for this project. I need to create a client that will call services from a wsdl. I already got that part running. I generated a C# class that wraps the wsdl into a service via "[wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)". I was able to implement it too, my problem is that, I need to use wsse headers when sending a request. wsdl.exe doesn't provide that by default, so I tweaked my code a bit so that I can send a request with wsse headers. Here's a snippet of my code that calls the service:

```
        using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens;
        using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
        using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //... some other code here ... 
        //create a credentials
        UsernameToken usernameToken = new UsernameToken("myUsername", "myPassword");

        //create a new instance of ApiService.
        ApiService apiClient = new ApiService();
        apiClient.Url = "http://something.com/something/soap/v2/";

        SoapContext context = apiClient.RequestSoapContext;
        context.Security.Tokens.Add(usernameToken);
        context.Security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(usernameToken));

        //call the sendFax method.
        myResponse response = apiClient.SendMyRequest(myRequest);
        }
```

This is a snippet of the code that I am invoking when calling "`sendRequest()`".

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MyResponse", Namespace="https://something.com/something/soap/v2", IsNullable=true)]
public myResponse SendMyRequest ([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="https://something.com/something/soap/v2", IsNullable=true)] myRequest MyRequest) {
            Console.WriteLine("sending message... ");
        object[] results = this.Invoke("SendMyRequest", new object[] {
                    MyRequest});
        return ((myResponse)(results[0]));
    }
    //some other code here.
```

Whenever I hit run, I get the error:

```
The security token could not be authenticated or authorized
```

Now, my question is:

- Is there a way for me to see the soap request being sent? I remember in java (I was using axis2 then), I would open the service generated and simply print the env and the entire request formed would come out. I'm asking because I want to know if the request being sent is correct. Once I see the request, maybe I can correct it. :)
- How do I get the response? (sorry, noob question. I've looked around google, and people post the request without posting how they printed it out. lol.)
- In this snippet of code:

  `[something]` **<---- what do you call this?** 
  `public class hello {` 
  `//some code here` 
  `}`

  Yeah, what is it called? Forgive me, this syntax is sort of new to me. Just tell me the term for it and I'll search it on google.

  - note: most of the variables and classes in the code were altered since I'm under an NDA. Your response and patience is highly appreciated. :(

Comment: `[something]` is called attribute. I think you can see if requests are sent ussing fiddler: http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: lol.. ok.. thanks :D I'll read more on that.

Comment: omg.. I was able to look at the request sent via fiddler. It seems to generate way more than just what I was expecting. No wonder I'm getting the error. :(